# Should I declare the most specific type as return type of method?

Tags: java, object-oriented, inheritance, return-type

In Android I can put only `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` objects in `Intent`:

```
Intent putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value);
```

I can't put in there a `List<? extends Parcelable>`.

I have **private** method that get list of `Parcelable` objects from `Intent` (i.e. the method is used in its own class).

As I said there is always `ArrayList` in `Intent`. Should I declare return type of this method as `ArrayList<>`?   Or `List<>`?

I think that `ArrayList` would be better because an `ArrayList` is also a `List`. But I often read that I should declare field type as most general possible type. *I.e.*, `Collection<>` (or `List<>` if I need ordered collection) instead of `ArrayList<>`. But I don't see any reason to do so for this method return type.

Comment: The method is private. It doesn't really matter. Killian makes a good point in general but in this case the amount of refactoring you would have to do later on if you need to change your list implementation is practically nil.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A declaration (whether a return type, an API comment or a contract) is a promise that you will deliver some good or perform some service. Declaring a specific return type is a greater promise than declaring a general type that is good enough for the caller, because it ties you down do a more specific action.

If that is really what you are doing *and always will be what you are doing*, then there's no problem with that. But if one day you want to refactor, extend or improve your program in a way that involves a new, better container type, you won't be able to, because client code would break if you switch to `CoolNewList` structures. Then you will say to yourself, "Gee, I wish I had listened to those wise people at StackExchange and made minimal promises instead of boasting with concrete types!", but it will be too late for you. Then you will start advising younger coders to keep their promises minimal, and so the cycle of life continues.

Comment: If this method is `private` ?

Comment: If it's private, you don't have to fear breaking client code, but you still have to fear breaking your own code. Fixing the caller is easier when you own the calling code yourself, but if you had returned `List`, *you wouldn't have to fix the caller at all*, so it's still better to declare `List` just to save type-related maintenance effort. Also, a utility method that returns `List` is way easier to understand than one that declares a fancy concrete type - a reader of the API will always think, "Hmm, I wonder if there's a gotcha that I ought to know about that `DoublyLinkedSkipList`..."

Comment: Do you know why the `Intent` method parameter type declared as `ArrayList` instead of `List` ?

Comment: It's partially a self-fulfilling prophecy. Experienced coders know that it's good to declare abstract types, so when they see someone declaring a concrete type, they assume that either the API developer is inexperienced, or that there is some reason why the specific type is named there. And unmentioned special conditions on the use of an API are very, very bad. Many if not most errors in complex systems arise because someone used a component that is *almost*, but not quite correct.

Comment: @LeonidSemyonov: It is hard to know *why* they did it without having been there when the API was written - given that all these methods exist since API level 1, it could be an oversight, performance considerations, convenience, or something else.

Comment: Upvoted this solely for this line: `"Gee, I wish I had listened to those wise people at StackExchange and made minimal promises instead of boasting with concrete types!"`, makes it easier to get the point accross to normal programmers